# Removing git commits after rebasing and merging in other branches that did similar

Tags: git, github

Being a beginner to git, I successfully managed to remove `package-lock.json` using `filter-branch` and a bunch of other dangerous git options from several different branches using several different computers.  After managing that, they all merged back into master, creating duplicates of many of the commits.

After a while, I decided to fix the problem, but it turned out that I couldn't `git rebase -i origin/master` without having a merge conflict on almost every single commit.  Additionally, even though the commits had merge conflicts and appeared when you did `git log`, they did not exist in the vim edit file when I did `git rebase`.

So I instead removed all parents of commits that were no longer being referenced by the current commit, and so now I have several commits with no parents and no real way to delete them.
Example:
https://github.com/Kimaitn/BlockchainMedicineTracker/commit/5c0f4732467ccf5ef3a81fb249cde621238f799c

Compare:
https://github.com/Kimaitn/BlockchainMedicineTracker/commit/49192a09dc6ab93973734f93b4c42908cbd30b53
with
https://github.com/Kimaitn/BlockchainMedicineTracker/commit/e463fa8447da8abaf94af741dfa0420f63831afa
(same edits, except one has no parent)

Trying to do anything with rebasing or cherry-picking completely destroys all commits afterwards and has merging errors.  There are about 5 commits so far that I need to just remove from the github; all of them are 'initial' commits with no parents.

What is the best approach to delete these?

UPDATE:
After looking through the commits with a GUI, I can see the commits I want to remove.  I guess they're lonely commits that seem a lot more difficult to be able to remove than I first thought, which kind of blows.  In this case, is there a way to effectively remove them?  The one in the picture is the highlighted node, although almost every single branch has the same commit (for example the two above the highlighted blue one, the green and yellow nodes, both have the same commit message and insertions/deletions).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRyfp.png)

Comment: You have used filter-branch, but did you git push --force that branch after that? (instead of merge) Are you alone working on that branch/repo?

Comment: oh, definitely.  That's how I got my entire master branch into a mess.  I separately used filter-branch and git push --force on 4 different computers, had everyone push to a different branch, and then merge into master. 

I did that to remove the node-modules from every branch, but apparently that's not a good idea because every merge had different histories instead of rebasing from master to 1 history.  That should answer the 'working alone' question though :(